# Spring batch 5 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to run a spring batch 5 in a bazel application, I have the configuration class as below and i have added the spring batch depedency  maven_artifact("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch") in bazel build file. I am using spring-boot = 2.5.14

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

 @Autowired
 private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
   @Autowired
   private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

   @Autowired
   private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

 @Autowired
 private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

 @Bean
   public Step myStep(Tasklet jobExecutorTasklet) {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
         .tasklet(jobExecutorTasklet)
         .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
         .build();
   }


 @Bean
   public Job myJob(Step myStep) {
     return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
         .start(myStep)
         .build();

   }


 @Bean
 public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5); // Set the maximum number of threads
   taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5); // Set the core number of threads
   taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10); // Set the queue capacity
   return taskExecutor;
 }

}
```

Getting this error when I try to start spring boot server:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:474) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:397) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:283) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:453) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at com.roku.ads.activation.amp.services.common.batch.BatchApp.main(BatchApp.java:24) ~[batch-server-binary.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        ... 23 common frames omitted

2023-10-21 02:46:27.011  WARN 42401 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JpaBatchConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@531d72ca]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:661) ~[processed_spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[processed_spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:913) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:901) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:888) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:828) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:353) ~[processed_spring-boot-2.5.14.jar:2.5.14]
        at com.roku.ads.activation.amp.services.common.batch.BatchApp.main(BatchApp.java:24) ~[batch-server-binary.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[processed_spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Spring-Batch 5.0+ requires Spring-Framework 6.0+, you should upgrade your spring-boot version from 2.5.4 to 3.x.x+.

[WhatsNew in Spring-Batch 5.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNew)